# Is this code still valid or too old? XML Field Rules Value Validation

Tags: xml, xsd

Basically, I want a value validation where there is one field that has a number, Field1 = # and then Field2 needs to have the same # (and give a little red error if it doesn't).

I'm seeing the following:

```
    <fieldRules xmlns="http://urlthatdoesn'texist" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <valueValidation><booleanRules><booleanRule type="Error">

    <expression type="WinWrap">Csng("0" &amp; "%Amount%") &lt;&gt; Csng("0" &amp; "%Amount%") 
</expression>

<message>Field1=Field2</message>
</booleanRule>
</booleanRules>
</valueValidation>
</fieldRules>
```

The problem is, I'm trying to figure out what is needed in this code and what isn't and google isn't really pointing me in the right direction. Do I need the xmlns url?

Comment: Why are you even _looking_ at that code if you don't understand it?

Comment: Because it's in something I do understand... and I want to change it and everyone else who did understand it isn't around anymore. So, I'm trying to learn it, but I'm not sure where to start, is why I'm starting with asking if this is current coding and if I need the xmlns url. That will give me some more information to research.

Comment: What context is this in? The XML by itself is not code.

Comment: You need to begin by identifying the schema language you're working in.  It's not XSD, and it's not Relax NG, and it's not DTDs; what is it?  The name of the default namespace, which you have carefully obfuscated, is the only clue.

Comment: Same response as CMSMcQ: this is code written in a schema language that I don't recognize. My guess would be that it's an in-house custom validation tool, or perhaps some open-source tool that never gained wide adoption.